# Combine pinned apps and tasklist/open clients

Tags: lua, window-managers, awesome-wm

In Awesome WM v4.3 (stable) I'm wanting to add 'pinned'/'favourite' apps to the tasklist, to display alongside the open clients listed there. Similar to how most desktop environments work.

As an example, say I have the following pinned apps:

- Firefox
- Thunderbird
- Alacritty

And then say I have the following non-pinned apps open:

- Nemo
- Geany

What I'd like the tasklist (or some new widget) to display is the following:
Firefox, Thunderbird, Alacritty, Nemo, Geany

If I click on Firefox (and it's not already running) a new instance would start, but the tasklist wouldn't change. Perhaps just an underline would appear under the Firefox pinned app to show it's open/running.

Is something like this possible with Awesome?

I have a working tasklist that just shows running apps, and I have a separate widget showing icons for specific/pinned apps that launch when clicked. I just need a way to combine them somehow. But not just next to each other (i.e. I don't want to run a pinned app and have it appear duplicated in the tasklist).